# What is this "join" doing?

Tags: python, list, join, expression

I just installed retext via pip. I have to download icons for it but I realise it doesn't work (no icons on the menu) unless i run "retext" in the folder of retext.

I tried to fix it but my python skills are not very strong.

At the moment, I force the icon_path to have the path I want.

```
#icon_path = 'icons/'
icon_path = '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/retext/icons/'
```

Can someone enlighten me how this line works?

```
datadirs = [join(d, 'retext') for d in datadirs]
```

Thanks.

```
import sys
import markups
import markups.common
from os.path import dirname, exists, join

from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QLocale, QSettings, QStandardPaths
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

app_version = "6.0.1"

settings = QSettings('ReText project', 'ReText')

if not str(settings.fileName()).endswith('.conf'):
        # We are on Windows probably
        settings = QSettings(QSettings.IniFormat, QSettings.UserScope,
                'ReText project', 'ReText')

datadirs = QStandardPaths.standardLocations(QStandardPaths.GenericDataLocation)
datadirs = [join(d, 'retext') for d in datadirs]

if sys.platform == "win32":
        # Windows compatibility: Add "PythonXXX\share\" path
        datadirs.append(join(dirname(sys.executable), 'share', 'retext'))

if '__file__' in locals():
        datadirs = [dirname(dirname(__file__))] + datadirs

#icon_path = 'icons/'
icon_path = '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/retext/icons/'
for dir in datadirs:
        if exists(join(dir, 'icons')):
                icon_path = join(dir, 'icons/')
                break
```

Comment: `join` comes from your final import statement: `from os.path import dirname, exists, join`. It is used for combining path segments. Read the official python docs on os.path for more info. `datadirs = [join(d, 'retext') for d in datadirs]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that combines every directory path in `datadirs` with the path segment `'retext'`. You're essentially getting the retext subfolder of every directory path in `datadirs`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin That actually is a great, concise answer. Never too late to transform it into a post, which clearly would get a  from me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> `os.path.join(path, *paths)`
>
> Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of path and any members of `*paths` with exactly one directory separator (`os.sep`) following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

It is imported here:

```
from os.path import dirname, exists, join
```

So, the line in question:

```
datadirs = [join(d, 'retext') for d in datadirs]
```

The `[`...`]` is a List Comprehension that builds a list of the results of `join(d, 'retext')` applied to each directory in the `datadirs` list.

So, if `datadirs` contained:

```
['/usr/local/test', '/usr/local/testing', '/usr/local/tester']
```

Then:

```
[join(d, 'retext') for d in datadirs]
```

Would produce:

```
['/usr/local/test/retext', '/usr/local/testing/retext', '/usr/local/tester/retext']
```

The problem with setting:

```
icon_path = '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/retext/icons/'
```

Is that it's being overwritten in the `for` loop, so unless a proper path is not found, it will be overwritten.